# Localization breaks button heights

Tags: html, css, localization

In a project to localize a web application, we realise that since browsers use different fonts for different languages (e.g. English and Japanese, or even two different japanese texts, depending on which glyphs are used), the height of some html objects changes, most obvious with input buttons.
Although this is understandable, what approach would you use to fix this? The only way I have found (which I don't really want to do as it breaks the idea of responsive design) is to set vertical-align to top, and height to a fixed pixel height.

To see what I mean, you can look at [this fiddle][1] 
in Chrome, the buttons will have different height.
In Firefox, the height will be the same. The reason being that the two Japenese texts will render with different fonts (Yu Gothic and Simsun, depending on which glyphs are used.

Any ideas please?

`[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/sxg78tom/3/`

Comment: Tried some things but nothing is working for me too - have you tried to find some japaneese/chineese fonts, so if you declare same font across browsers, in theory they should be the same and than you can alter things on buttons...

OR, if you don't want to use included fonts, you can add classes to japaneese/chineese buttons and then alter the height by adding padding to one of buttons. You can also target this for specific browser, e.g. `@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
 #hej2{padding:5px;} 
}` for chrome

Comment: @Zorak It's nothing complicated, just make them flexible literally :)

Comment: @Highdef I have seen your solution and I admit, that it is better. However without futher details, we dont know, if the inputs can be in additional div. if not, this problem can get little bit more complicated :) I have followed exact structure.

Comment: @Zorak The div just acts as a container to keep them nothing else, you can make use of a span for that matter. But its the only clean way I know to workaround with that problem without any issues.

Comment: You could atleast respond or rate to the only answer of your query seeing that it works. Would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, yes I think I would go for the flex model, as e.g. Macs and PCs tend to have differnet fonts, and the general problem with Web Fonts being usually limited to a certain character set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of this:
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3u1wahy9/

- Wrap your `input elements (in this case the buttons)` inside a div which has the CSS style of `inline-flex`, this will make all the elements flexible i.e making them obtain the same height. Hope, this helps.

```css
div{
  display:inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div>
<input id="hej" type="submit"  value="ファイルの" style="vertical-align:top;font-size:1em;"/>
<input id="hej2" type="submit"  value="選択" style="vertical-align:top;font-size:1em;" />
</div>
```

Comment: @JJohansson No problem :)